# how to implement fill in the blank in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

"I _____ any questions."

I want to implement a quiz that clicks parentheses in that phrase and puts the correct answer by typing the keyboard in the parentheses.

Every time I get a letter, the underline also increases and I have no idea how to implement it.

Please advise me how to implement that in Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@leka2002 Let try with this,

```
let underlineAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue]

var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()

attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: String(format: "%@ ", "Your Answer"), attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : .red, NSAttributedString.Key.font : font])

attributedString.addAttributes(underlineAttribute, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: "Your Answer".count))
```

"Your Answer" is `Every time you get a letter`  - you need use String variable for this. Then assign like `label.attributedString = attributedString`

I hope it will work what you expect.